# I want join two tables in one with spring boot query

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two tables and I want to merge these two tables in one by join, but I can't show all columns like id in user id and app_user_id.

I am creating a new entity have result from join of these two tables:

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class UserDetails implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "mobile_number")
    private Long mobileNumber;

    //  private String userId;

    @Column(name = "app_user")
    private Long appUserId;

    public Long getApp_user_id() {
        return appUserId;
    }

    public void setApp_user_id(Long app_user_id) {
        this.appUserId = app_user_id;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = Constants.LOGIN_REGEX)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "first_name", length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "last_name", length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Email
    @Size(min = 5, max = 254)
    @Column(length = 254, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean activated = false;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "lang_key", length = 10)
    private String langKey;

    @Size(max = 256)
    @Column(name = "image_url", length = 256)
    private String imageUrl;

    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(Long mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean isActivated() {
        return activated;
    }

    public void setActivated(boolean activated) {
        this.activated = activated;
    }

    public String getLangKey() {
        return langKey;
    }

    public void setLangKey(String langKey) {
        this.langKey = langKey;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserDetails that = (UserDetails) o;
        return activated == that.activated &&
            Objects.equals(id, that.id) &&
            Objects.equals(mobileNumber, that.mobileNumber) &&
            Objects.equals(login, that.login) &&
            Objects.equals(firstName, that.firstName) &&
            Objects.equals(lastName, that.lastName) &&
            Objects.equals(email, that.email) &&
            Objects.equals(langKey, that.langKey) &&
            Objects.equals(imageUrl, that.imageUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, mobileNumber, login, firstName, lastName, email, activated, langKey, imageUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserDetails{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", mobileNumber=" + mobileNumber +
            ", login='" + login + '\'' +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", activated=" + activated +
            ", langKey='" + langKey + '\'' +
            ", imageUrl='" + imageUrl + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
}
```

and I create a new repository for new entity:

```
    @Repository
public interface UserDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<UserDetails,Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT a.id as app_user, u.id, u.login as login ,u.first_name ,u.last_name  ,u.email ,u.activated ,u.lang_Key ,u.image_Url ,a.mobile_number   FROM jhi_user AS u join app_user AS a WHERE a.user_id=u.id ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<UserDetails> joinTable();


}
```

In this repository I have written a query run in SQL command but in spring I am getting different results.

This is my result in spring :

```
UserDetails{id=0ea8e6e2-fb1f-43e8-aee1-b14ea2b9ef17, mobileNumber=780344248, login='semon@test.com', firstName='semon', lastName='hyari', email='semon@test.com', activated=true, langKey='en', imageUrl='null'}
```

I want show this result

```
UserDetails{id=0ea8e6e2-fb1f-43e8-aee1-b14ea2b9ef17,**userId="value"**, mobileNumber=780344248, login='semon@test.com', firstName='semon', lastName='hyari', email='semon@test.com', activated=true, langKey='en', imageUrl='null'}
```

Comment: I think its because you are missing getter/setter is entity class.

Answer (score 0):

Just add getter/setter for missing attribute in your `entity` class. I see `id` is already there but `app_user_id` is missing cause no getter/setter in the entity.